# Excel VBA loop through columns in range and copy columns

Tags: vba, loops, excel

I am new to Excel VBA and need some help writing a macro.

From `Worksheet1` of `Workbook1` I need to copy each column of range `D1:Z100`, one at a time, and pasteValue it to cells `B1:B100`.

This triggers a calculation in `Worksheet2` of `Workbook1`. Here I need to copy cells `A1:B200` into a new workbook.

This new workbook is to be renamed with the text string in `Worksheet1`, cell `B1`. The new workbook is to be saved into the same folder as `Workbook1`.

The loop is then to continue with the next column from `Worksheet1`, and continue until all columns in the range have been treated this way.

I have used two days searching the net to find an answer without any luck....

Comment: Please check range of columns it should be D1 : Z1

Answer (score -1):

Start the way most of us did:

1. Record new macro.
2. Manually perform all the steps you want to automate.
3. Stop recording.
4. Go to the Developer tab and inspect the auto-generated code.
5. Write your own VBA based on what you learn in Step 4.

You will have to figure out a few things on your own, or come back here and ask specific questions.